# Estimating singular double integral

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

How can I estimate
$$\int_{(0,1) \setminus B_{\delta}(1/2)} \int_{B_\delta(1/2)} \frac{u(y)v(y)}{|x-y|^{\alpha +1}} \, dy \, dx$$ in terms of a positive power of  $\delta$ and suitable norms of $u$ and $v$? Here we assume $\alpha \in (0,2)$, $u \in L^2$ and $v \in C^2$.

Comment: Do $u$ and $v$ here have the same argument, $y$? If so, why can't we replace $uv$ by one function $w$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Yes, they have the same argument $y$

Comment: @IosifPinelis Yes, we can: I wrote it like this because this is the way it appears in my context, but for the sake of the question I guess you can write $w$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand\de\delta\newcommand\De\Delta$Let $a:=\alpha\in(0,2)$ and $w:=uv$. Then all we can get from your conditions on $u,v$ is that $w\in L^2$. The integral in question is
$$I:=\int_{B_\de(1/2)}dy\, w(y)J(y),$$
where, for $y\in B_\de(1/2)$,
$$J(y):=\int_{(0,1)\setminus B_\de(1/2)}\frac{dx}{|x-y|^{a+1}} \\
=\frac1a\,\Big(\frac1{(y-(1/2-\de))^a}-\frac1{y^a}-\frac1{(1-y)^a}+\frac1{(1/2+\de-y)^a}\Big)\asymp\frac1a\,\frac1{\De(y)^a}$$
if $\de>0$ is small enough, where $\De(y)$ is the shortest distance from $y$ to the set $\{1/2-\de,1/2+\de\}$.

So, the best upper bound on $|I|$ in terms of $\|w\|_2$ is given by
$$|I|\le\|w\|_2\,\sqrt{\int_{B_\de(1/2)}dy\,J(y)^2} \\
\asymp\frac{\|w\|_2}a\,\sqrt{\int_{B_\de(1/2)}\frac{dy}{\De(y)^{2a}}} \\ 
\asymp\frac{\|w\|_2\,\de^{1/2-a}}{a\,\sqrt{1/2-a}}$$
if $a\in(0,1/2)$; otherwise, $|I|$ can be infinite.

Similarly, the best upper bound on $|I|$ in terms of $\|w\|_\infty$ is given by
$$|I|\le\|w\|_\infty\,\int_{B_\de(1/2)}dy\,J(y) \\
\asymp\frac{\|w\|_\infty}a\,\int_{B_\de(1/2)}\frac{dy}{\De(y)^a} \\ 
\asymp\frac{\|w\|_\infty\,\de^{1-a}}{a\,(1-a)}$$
if $a\in(0,1)$; otherwise, $|I|$ can be infinite.

Comment: Thank you very much! How would the answer change if we considered the first integral $\int_{(0,1) \setminus (B_{2\delta}(1/2) \setminus B_{\delta}(1/2))}$?

Comment: @Lao : Then you would allow $x$ to be in $B_\delta(1/2)$, which is the interval where $y$ lives. So, then the analog of $J(y)$ would be $\infty$ for each $y\in B_\delta(1/2)$, and hence, in general, there will be no finite bound on $I$ at all. If you have any additional questions, it is better to ask them in separate posts.